# Detect Failed Icon 'load'

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts

Is there a way to know if a hex code fails to map/encode to an icon? For example; if I place the following on a page:

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xe307;</i>
```

It shows an icon of a computer screen. If I do the following it shows junk/nothing:

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xe306;</i>
```

In the below image the left icon is `&#xe306;` and the right is `&#xe307;`:

[image]

In javascript I want to detect when an icon does/does not map to a valid icon. I know I can do something similar for images, ie, I can hook a load event and detect if the image src url is invalid. Is there something similar I can do for icons?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you would have to inspect the font itself.

Comment: @DanielA.White do you know if javascript can do such a thing client side? The font file is a `.woff2`.